# Cannot find module 'ts-jest/dist/config/config-set'

Tags: jestjs, vuejs3, ts-jest

I'm trying to use jest on a vite+vue3+typescript project.
Unfortunatly jest continue to fail with a 'Cannot find module 'ts-jest/dist/config/config-set' message.

The file 'ts-jest/dist/config/config-set' don't exists in my nodeModules but I don't know how to install it. It would be the simpliest way to resolve this bug I hope.

Here's my package.json configuration:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^29.1.0",
    "@vue/composition-api": "^1.7.1",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^2.0.0-rc.18",
    "babel-jest": "27.5.1",
    "fuzzysort": "^2.0.1",
    "jest": "^29.1.1",
    "ts-jest": "^29.0.3",
    "vue": "^3.2.37"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.38.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.38.1",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^3.1.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^11.0.2",
    "@vue/vue3-jest": "27.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.22.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.5.1",
    "sass": "^1.55.0",
    "sass-loader": "^13.0.2",
    "typescript": "^4.8.4",
    "vite": "^3.1.0",
    "vue-tsc": "^0.40.4"
  },
  "moduleDirectories": [
    "node_modules",
    "src"
  ]
```

jest.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    moduleFileExtensions: [
        'js',
        'ts',
        'json',
        'vue'
    ],
    transform: {
        '^.+\\.ts$': 'ts-jest',
        '^.+\\.vue$': '@vue/vue3-jest'
    },
    testMatch: [
        '**/(src)/**/*.spec.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)|**/__tests__/*.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)',
    ],
}
```

And the tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "lib": ["ESNext", "DOM"],
    "types": ["vite/client", "@types/jest"],
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.d.ts", "src/**/*.tsx", "src/**/*.vue"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json"}]
}
```

Comment: I made it works just before sleeping ヽ(´▽`)/ - Now I’m trying to understand. Maybe it’s the way I added the ts-jest package (without —dev’ dependencies). I want to know

Answer (score 0):

It works with:

package.json

```
{
  "name": "MerxBiblio",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vue-tsc --noEmit && vite build",
    "serve": "vite preview",
    "test": "jest src"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "fuzzysort": "^2.0.1",
    "vue": "^3.2.16"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.2",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^1.9.3",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^2.0.0-rc.15",
    "@vue/vue3-jest": "^27.0.0-alpha.1",
    "jest": "^27.2.5",
    "ts-jest": "^27.0.5",
    "typescript": "^4.4.3",
    "vite": "^2.6.4",
    "vue-tsc": "^0.3.0",
    "sass": "^1.55.0",
    "sass-loader": "^13.0.2"
  }
}
```

jest.config.js

```
  moduleFileExtensions: [
    'js',
    'ts',
    'json',
    'vue'
  ],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.ts$': 'ts-jest',
    '^.+\\.vue$': '@vue/vue3-jest'
  },
  testEnvironment: "jsdom"
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "lib": ["esnext", "dom"],
    "types": ["@types/jest"]
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.d.ts", "src/**/*.tsx", "src/**/*.vue"]
}
```